# InteractiveMarker hook into mouseover/hover?

Tags: ros, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to execute a callback for an interactive marker on mouseover? I can capture and click event and use it just fine, but I'd like to be able to capture a mouseover (or hover) event as well. The markers already highlight on mouseover, so I'm hoping it isn't difficult. Does anyone know how to do this? I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Groovy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56160/interactivemarker-hook-into-mouseover/hover?/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2013-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's not supported. What do you want to do with this?

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-02-24**:
I'm using Rviz to make a GUI that allows people to hand label point cloud data. I take a point cloud and build a PCL octree, then, for each leaf in the octree, I draw an interactive marker. Right now I have written a panel for the user to select a label, and what I would like is for the user...

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-02-24**:
...to be able to "paint" the markers with the selected label by just running the mouse cursor over the markers containing the point cloud points to be labelled. As it stands, I can click the markers individually, but that's time consuming. Would you have any suggestions?

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-02-24**:
Maybe this (undocumented) tutorial gets closer to what you want: https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/blob/groovy-devel/interactive_marker_tutorials/src/selection.cpp

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-02-24**:
Otherwise, you might want to look into writing an RViz plugin that provides it's own labeling tool that is similar to the 'Selection' tool.

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-02-24**:
Ah, that looks like it might be promising. Thanks!